# Как подключить функцию JS в html  ссылку через jsfiddle.net

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Начинаю учить JavaScript и столкнулся с такой проблемой, как подключение функции к коду html [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/Yres/exk57tnp/7/).

Нужно подключить функцию ShowMassege к ссылке: "Вывести отрицательные числа".

Comment: @UG45, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/exk57tnp/8/

Чтобы ссылка не срабатывала, не забывайте ставить в обработчике `onclick - return false;` либо в конце тела функции, которая вызывается по событию, в данном случае это `showMassege()`:

```
onClick="showMassege();return false;"
```